# Displaying a number as a string

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I receive a `NSDictionary` using `AFNetworking`. that dictionary has many values.

one of these I think is an `INT` or `NSNumber`, dont know what's the automatic conversion. The numbers expected are 2 and 3 but somehow I always get a very long number... I tried all the things I know and could find but I cant get it to show the right number in the

```
cell.numberOfLikes.text
```

These are all the things I've tried with no success. I would appreciate some guidance

```
NSLog(@"%i",_myDownloadedInfo[@"routines"][indexPath.row][@"routine"][@"routineDownloads"]);

   NSLog(@"%i",[NSNumber numberWithInt:_myDownloadedInfo[@"routines"][indexPath.row][@"routine"][@"routineDownloads"]]);

    cell.numberOfDownloads.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",_myDownloadedInfo[@"routines"][indexPath.row][@"routine"][@"routineDownloads"]]; 

cell.numberOfLikes.text =_myDownloadedInfo[@"routines"][indexPath.row][@"routine"][@"routineDownloads"]);
```

Comment: What does this have to do with `AFNetworking`? Your question is about getting a number from a dictionary. The source of the dictionary is irrelevant.

Comment: You're logging pointers as integers.  This will tend to produce large numbers.  (You're also ignoring warning messages from the compiler, I suspect.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `%i` format specified is for basic, integer data types. Since you have (or try to create) an `NSNumber` object, you can use `%@` to log it. `%@` is used for Objective-C objects in format specifiers.

But that doesn't help when you want to assign the `NSNumber` to your text field. You need to convert the number to an `NSString`. Ideally you should use an `NSNumberFormatter` to convert the `NSNumber` to an `NSString`.

Do this:

```
NSNumber *likesNumber = _myDownloadedInfo[@"routines"][indexPath.row][@"routine"][@"routineDownloads"];
NSString *numberText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d". [likesNumber intValue]];
NSLog(@"Number: %@", numberText);
cell.numberOfLikes.text = numberText;
```

Comment: or `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", number.intValue]` to avoid the need for learning even more APIs.

Comment: Who the hell is downvoting? (+1 for you to compensate)

Comment: @H2CO3 But using `stringWithFormat` won't format the number properly based on the user's locale. Of course with `int` values that isn't as much of an issue as with `float` values.

Comment: This is what worked. NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[_myDownloadedInfo[@"routines"][indexPath.row][@"routine"][@"routineDownloads"] intValue]])   dont know if it is the best way to do it but it works

Comment: @JonathanThurft That's overkill. Do one or other, not both.

Comment: @JonathanThurft **Do not do that!** Ever. It's just plain superfluous. Why would you log an `NSString` created using the `stringWithFormat:` method? Why don't you directly log it using `%d` in the format string passed to `NSLog()`?

Comment: If i dont put intValue it doesnt convert. the number is an id

Comment: @JonathanThurft Have you **read** the answer? `%i` is for `int` which is what `intValue` produces. `%@` is for Objective-C object, which is the number object itself.

Answer (score 1):

Several points.

- First, the first argument of NSLog is a format specifier.  It is entirely equivalent to the format specifier used in `[NSString stringWithFormat:]` and there's rarely a need for both.
- Next, data in Objective-C can be individual `int` values, `char` values, `char*` values (which are C strings), float values, and Objective-C object values.  (Plus a few assorted long, unsigned, etc values that you rarely use.)
- An NSString is an Objective-C object, as is an NSNumber.  An NSInteger, on the other hand, is an alias for a particular size of `int` and generally interchangeable with `int`.  Very often people get confused with NSNumber (object) vs NSInteger (scalar int) -- they are *not* the same.
- In an NSLog or stringWithFormat specifier you use `%` followed by one or more characters to indicate how a value (in the following list of values) is to be formatted.  `%d` or `%i` is an `int`.  (`%d` is preferred.)  `%f` is a simple floating-point value (but the formatting of these can get more complicated).  `%s` is a C-style string (ie, a `char*` value).  `%@` is used for formatting an Objective-C object.  You use `%@`, in particular, to format an NSString or (to get the default presentation) an NSNumber.

It's important to understand how `%@` works in a format string.  When the format interpreter encounters it, it interprets the next item in the value list as a pointer to an Objective-C object and invokes the `description` method of that object.  An NSString just returns itself as the result of `description`, while an NSNumber returns an NSString that represents the character representation of the number's value.  Other objects (all Objective-C objects support `description`, if only by default) return either a simple identification of the object type or a representation of the object's internal values.

So, if you have an NSNumber, you can directly format it with `%@`, or you can extract the numeric value (eg, `[someNSNumber intValue]`) and then format that value appropriately (eg, `%d`).  A reason for doing the latter would be if you wanted to specify the column width for the number (eg, `%5d`, to format the number into a 5-position field).

See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1) for some (gory) details on the various format specifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: `%i` is the conversion specifier for `int`.

> one of these I think is an INT or NSNumber, dont know what's the automatic conversion

Now go back and read the documentation of `NSArray`, think about whether or not it can contain `int`s, then proceed reading.

---

So the objects in the dictionary are instances of `NSNumber` -> they're Objective-C objects -> they are implemented using pointers. Poor `NSLog()` tries to convert the pointer value to an integer. Either use `%@` to get the description of the number, or `%i` and `[theNumber intValue]` to print its integer value.